# Should I export configuration from a module file or parse it from another file?

Tags: perl

I have a script that requires password, login and other custom settings from the user. As of right now I have it hardcoded inside the perl script. It is somewhat troublesome, because I'm constantly working in it and commiting it back to a public remote git repository. And everytime I commit the changes I have to remember to unset the variables with personal information and custom settings.

So I was wondering whether I should create a module just to wrap this variables and then use the module inside the script or if I should create a file (json, xml, text, whatever) and then parse this file on my script to get the personal information and settings. The people who'll use the script are no strange to programming, so it's not like an organized file will make things easier on the end user side. Since I'm a noob, I don't see why should I parse a file when I could just use the module, that's why I'm inclined to use the module. Is it a bad practice?

Comment: But... wouldn't you then put your module under version control and have the same problem that you have now? Better to commit a sample file to version control (_file.sample.conf_) and set the real one (_file.conf_) to be ignored.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking about commiting once (as a template) and then never adding it to the commit again. So for every change in my script i could use `git add myscript.pl` and the changes to `mymodule.pm` wouldn't be commited. But thinking about it, it does seem quite bad.

Comment: You would definitely want to put the config in its own file separate from any logic, and put that file into your .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy that works reasonably well is to create a template/example config file and only put *that* file under version control. You would then set the "real" config file to be ignored using whatever constructs your revision control system provides for that task. (Here's how to do it in [Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html), [Git](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), and [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore).)

For example, you might check in *app.sample.conf*, which other people would then copy to *app.conf* upon checkout/cloning of your repo.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to put a sample config with dummy values in version control, and set it up so that the real config file is ignored by the version control system so it doesn't accidentally get checked in as well.

Alternatively, you could go with the [twelve-factor](http://12factor.net) [solution](http://12factor.net/config) and get your configuration values from environment variables instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is ask the user for the creds on first run, saving them to a configuration file that will never be needed in your git repo. After the first run, the user can then edit this config file to change the details. However, having a sample file in your git repo with defaults will allow a user to manually set one up by themselves though.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Config::Tiny;

my $file = 'myapp.ini';
my $config = Config::Tiny->new;

my ($un, $pw);

if (! -e $file){

    print "what's your username?: ";
    $config->{user}{un} = <>;

    print "what's your password?: ";
    $config->{user}{pw} = <>;

    $config->write($file);
}

$config = $config->read($file);

$un = $config->{user}{un};
$pw = $config->{user}{pw};

print "un: $un, pw: $pw\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the distinction is less between *code* and *data*, and more about whether a particular chunk of the project is *mutable* or not. This is most clear with declarative languages like CSS and HTML, where it is hard to say whether we are talking about code or data, compared to JavaScript, which is clearly “code” just because it is procedural

Even mutability is hard to tie down because it depends on a particular *view* of the project. During development everything is mutable, whereas after deployment everything is fixed except the documents that the application works with and the configuration data. It can even be said that the configuration is “less” mutable than the app's documents

The HTML, CSS and JavaScript model of web pages is also useful to show another clear distinction: that of *purpose*. The trinity correspond to the *content*, *presentation* and *functionality* of a web page respectively, and I think we can draw from this the guiding principle to “keep like layers together”, whether the sameness is in mutability, purpose, or something else that we haven't thought of yet

Regardless, I think configuration data is different from any other part of the project in almost every way. It is both code and data, and it can be thought of initially as just another app document until a couple of years have passed without it being changed, when it becomes immutable, or effectively so, and really part of the code

One other thing I want to throw into the mix here is that I believe an application should work and do *something* sensible and useful without any configuration at all. The obvious way to do this is to have a default configuration that is loaded and used when the app starts up and finds itself without custom config data. At that point it will pull in the default config and start running accordingly, writing the current steup to a live config when the app exits

My recommendation then is to write a *default* config file that is part of the project, and have the app use that only when it is started in a vacuum. Thereafter a live config file will be maintained that can be edited as desired. The default and the live config should be in the same format, and since we don't want to be writing Perl modules to store our config data, they should be in XML, YAML, JSON, or whatever. The default config will be part of the proiject, and the live config will be treated like a very special application document